# Angular change Background of clicked ngFor li

Tags: html, css, angular, ngfor

I have an ul element with some li's Im getting those li's with *ngFor.
Their background color is white but I want to change the background color to red if I click on them. But I only want to change the background color of the li I clicked on and not every li.

```
<div class="Container">
  <h1>My Children</h1>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li style="cursor: pointer" class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let Child of children" (click)="onChildSelect(Child)" >{{Child.Name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add this to your li:

```
[style.background-color]="Child.IsChildSelected"
```

Making it:

```
<li style="cursor: pointer" class="list-group-item" 
    *ngFor="let Child of children" (click)="onChildSelect(Child)" 
    [style.background-color]="Child.BackgroundColour" >
```

Then your click function should change the child background colour (you can return it as a string). eg:

```
onChildSelect(Child)
{
    // This would work but if you have the previously selected child stored 
    // it would be better to just turn that one white
    for (let myChild of this.children) {
        myChild.BackgroundColour = "white";
    }

    Child.BackgroundColour = "red";
}
```

You can make the function more complex to have multiple colours or change the other children to a non selected colour if necessary.

Comment: but how does that change the color?

Comment: Oops, hold on, I missed a part out

Comment: Thank you thats working but i've got  a problem. If i click on the first child its color changes to red and when i click on it again it changes back to white as i want it to but if i click on the first one and then on the second one i want the first one to change to white again and the second one to red. But since we clicked on the second one we dont have the first child in our function anymore so i cant change it back...

Comment: Do you not have this.children accessible to you? You could make all children white when a child is selected before making the newly selected child red.

Comment: yea i can access this.children but how do i set the entire array to white?

Comment: can i get the index of the selected child in the children array? Then i could save the index number and use it in the second onclick to turn it white

Comment: You could give your child a UID which could be the same as the child's index and will remain so as long as you don't plan on sorting or changing your list.

Comment: Sounds complicated :D I just leave it the way it is ^^
Thanks anyway :D